# setting up VS Code for C++ with gcc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup my VS Code to use it to learn C++. I followed all the instructions of the tutorial, and when I ran the first, simple, 'hello world' application, I had no problems.
However, when I try to run the 2nd version (code following), it seems to... not be doing much? - nothing is printed to the console, though no error is thrown. When I add a breakpoint it is ignored. When I change the stopAtEntry in launch.json to true, still nothing happens (which is to say the build seems to run, I get a message saying that the build completed successfully, but nothing is printed to the console, nor is any debugging stops happening).
When I comment out the code and uncomment the original (simpler) code, there is no problem. Further, when I pasted the more advanced version of the code to an online compiler, it ran successfully with the expected result.
Finally, I discovered that I think the problem is with this line of code:

```
vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};
```

because when I comment it out, with the original line active, there is no problem, however if I try to have both lines active, again, what I described above happens.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};
    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
}
```

The 'simple' version:

```
std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
```

I followed the download and installation instructions for GCC to the letter and the tests they supplied for successful installation and path configuration are all working.

EDIT: in the debug console, I found this error message:

```
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.
```

EDIT: I am using a windows 10

Comment: I should also add that at this point I am not understanding what the code is doing, as I haven't actually started LEARNING C++, I am just following the instructions to make sure I have it setup and configured so that I can start learning it.

Comment: The range of possible problems has no limit. Without any additional information it's not really possible to determine anything authoritative. Either there's something wrong with your software installation, or you're missing some alert or error message, somewhere, that provides a specific indication as to what the problem is.

Comment: I actually found an error message, hiding in the debug console: ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide details. Don't dump relevant information into comments.

Comment: Yep, just added that error to the main question

Comment: Now, provide the details of what operating system you are using. And if it's MacOS, head over to http://www.google.com, type in the exact error message and see a bunch of links that explain what the issue is, and how to fix it.

Comment: Windows error codes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499- (at least enough of them to cover error 0x139)

Comment: Side note: Visual Studio Code can be a <expletive deleted> to configure correctly. Can I talk you into using plain old [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) to start learning with? It almost always works correctly right out of the box. Once you know C++ better, you'll be able to sort out what mistakes are code and what aren't.

Comment: @user4581301 It is a fairly nice editor with a highly configurable plugin environment. But way too frequently I see [c++] questions that are just misconfigurations of VS Code.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe it pains me to suggest Visual Studio because I utterly hate its editor, but I can't deny that it is easy to use and has one of the best mainstream debuggers since td32. My preferred tool I won't suggest to any new programmer. It suits me like a glove, though.

Comment: @user4581301 Fine, I'll say it. Clion has been for the past few years the best tool by quite a margin for regular C++ development. They have free editions for anyone with a student mail. I agree, vim isn't for everyone.